# CSS all initial breaks firefox newline in textareas

Tags: html, css, firefox, whitespace

Newline in textareas doesn't work in firefox when `all: initial` is set ...

https://jsfiddle.net/2bhzxdmg/

A idea how to resolve this (And I mean not be don't using the `all: initial` ... that is obvious)?

```css
textarea {
  all: initial;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can solve it by adding `white-space: pre-wrap`:

> Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary,
>   and on line breaks. (Source:
>   [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp))

The `white-space` is *not preserved* in Firefox because of the difference in initial user agent styles for `textarea`.

See demo below:

```js
document.getElementById('sub').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('text').value);
})
```

```css
textarea {
  all: initial;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<button id="sub">Get</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the browser's inspect tools to see what the default styles are without `all:initial`.
The default `white-space` property for a textarea turns out to be `pre-wrap`. So, that's the solution.

```css
textarea {
  all: initial;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  white-space: pre-wrap;  /* here you go. */
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```